# onAnimationEnd not called when Fragment onPause

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, animation

```
object : Animation.AnimationListener {
    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
        Log.d("TAG", " onAnimationEnd")
        // do something
    }
    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {}
    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {}
}
```

I use a animation and setAnimationListener.
AnimationListener `onAnimationEnd` is works.

but if I change to other fragment, `onAnimationEnd` will not be called.

I try to use `Handler` or `Coroutine` to startAnimation in background but still not works.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);